# Take All Html Table Data And Show in alert through loop javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i Want to add loop to read all html table rows data which are "Input text" and want to show all the "Input text" data according to row  as alert by click  once on submit this code is only working for one table row data which
is generated

```js
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var textf1  = '<input type="text" value="Fname1" id="text1" />';
    var textf2  = '<input type="text" value="Fname2" id="text2" /> ';
    cell1.innerHTML = textf1;
    cell2.innerHTML = textf2;
    cell3.innerHTML = textf4;
}


function first(){

    }
    alert("Hello"+text1.value+"Your Surname Is "+text2.value+" You Have Chosen");
    return myFunction()
    }

<
```

```html
<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<table id="myTable"></table>
<table id="myTable1"></table>
<br>
<div id="first"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Your First row</button>
<button onclick="Submit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: "i Want to make loop" Why don't you make then? Don't know any loop structure? Please describe your actual problem. Also, there seems to be nothing to submit in the code.

Comment: Side note, debug with the console, not alerts.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You say what you want, but not what you're having difficulty with in implementing that. You show some code. Is that your attempt? Does it give an error? Consider [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27905924/edit) your question to add this, and any other relevant, information.

Comment: Its My Reqirement @Teemu which is not possible for me

Comment: Noone can fullfill your requirements with that information, please add details and what you've tried so far, we're not going to write your code from scratch.

Comment: You can start at MDN and [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), or [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/?s=selectors).

Answer (score 0):

No so much a solution, but this might get you going.

To create a new row...

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton">Add Row</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
     $('#mytable tr:last').after('<tr><td>...</td></tr>');
});
```

To "loop" through your table...

**jQuery**

```
// Each row in your table.
$('#mytable> tbody  > tr').each(function (key, row) {
    var $row = $(row);
    var $input = $row.find(':input');

    // Each input for the given row.
    $.each($input, function (key, element) {
        var $element = $(element);

        console.log($element);
    });
});
```